# Cómo integrar una función que repita If statements hasta que se cumpla x condición

Tags: javascript

La función `convertHTML("Dolce & Gabbana & Dolce");` debe convertir los &,<,>,"", y ' que encuentre en el argumento a los valores de html correspondientes: &ampersand...etc

```js
function convertHTML(str) {
 var ampersand = "&amp;"
 var left = "&lt;"
 var right = "&gt;"
 var doubleq = "&quot;"
 var singleq = "&apos;";


 if (str.includes("&")){
  var newStr = str.replace(/&/g, ampersand);
  }
 else if (str.includes("<")){
  var newStr = str.replace(/</g, left);
  }
 else if (str.includes(">")){
  var newStr = str.replace(/>/g, right);
  }
 else if (str.includes('"')){
  var newStr = str.replace(/"/g, doubleq);
  }
 else if (str.includes("'")){
  var newStr = str.replace(/'/g, singleq);
  }
 else {return str}


  return newStr;
}
```

He hecho la función pero hay una situación en la que no funciona y es si en el argumento se dan dos entidades html diferentes: `convertHTML("<>")` Entonces sólo convierte la primera que se encuentra: `// Resultado: "&lt;>"`

Imagino que hay otra manera de hacerlo para que checkee las dos diferentes pero me preguntaba si podía arreglar esto sin tener que encarar el problema de forma diferente, es decir, poner arriba una función `checkear()` que compruebe si todavía existen caracteres sin convertir, y si todavía existen pues que los If statemente de abajo se vuelvan a ejecutar.

```js
function convertHTML(str) {
 var ampersand = "&amp;"
 var left = "&lt;"
 var right = "&gt;"
 var doubleq = "&quot;"
 var singleq = "&apos;";

 function checkear{
   if ((str.includes("&") || str.includes("<") || str.includes(">") || str.includes('"') || str.includes("'")){
  primerCheck() // vuelve a ejecutar los If statement de abajo
   }
 else {return newStr}
  }

    function primerCheck(){
 if (str.includes("&")){
  var newStr = str.replace(/&/g, ampersand);
  }
 else if (str.includes("<")){
  var newStr = str.replace(/</g, left);
  }
 else if (str.includes(">")){
  var newStr = str.replace(/>/g, right);
  }
 else if (str.includes('"')){
  var newStr = str.replace(/"/g, doubleq);
  }
 else if (str.includes("'")){
  var newStr = str.replace(/'/g, singleq);
  }
 else {return str}
}

 checkear()

  return newStr;
}
```

Pero me estoy perdiendo en los scopes y bueno, no se si esto se puede hacer más sencillo y es posible, o estoy perdiendo el tiempo y debería empezar todo de nuevo.

Comment: Te devuelve la primera que encuentra porque estás usando el `if` de manera incorrecta. De hecho te devolverá la primera que evalúe cuando se ejecute. Creo que deberías usar un `.split`, luego recorrer el `Array` resultante y reemplazar, y por último usar un `.join`. En fin que opciones tienes varias. Saludos

Comment: Lo que debes identificar para en un futuro que te presentes con algo así es que cuando utilizas sentencias `if` seguido un `else if` entonces tú código entra a un solo `if` no a los dos, aunque la condición que esté evaluando el `else if` sea verdadera, si ya entró en el `if` o `else if` anterior, no entra en ningún otro. La forma fácil de resolver lo que tenías sin explicar muchas cosas más de código es cambiar los `else if` por `if` nada más

Comment: @GermanAlzate cierto, parece mentira que todavía no tuve en cuenta eso. El caso es que ayer antes de acabar probé a poner If sólo, y me daba error. Se supone que debe funcionar correctamente, no? Puse un else al final, eso puede ser la razón de que diese error?

Comment: No, el error no era por dejar solo `if` con el `else` seguramente el siguiente error que te seguía era porque estabas intentando redefinir una variable ya definida, es decir por usar `var` para que eso no te sucediera tienes que al principio de tu función definir `var newStr = ''` y luego dentro de cada `if` quitar el `var` y solo dejar `newStr = str.replace...` Otro error que posiblemente tendrías es lo mismo que comenté en la respuesta que te dieron, mira el comentario y lo identificarás

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas complicandote muuuucho la vida. La razón por la que solo sustituye uno es porque solo entra una vez en el if. La solución no es entrar muchas veces en el if, sino simplemente hacer replaces de todo:

```js
function convertHTML(str) {
 var ampersand = "&amp;"
 var left = "&lt;"
 var right = "&gt;"
 var doubleq = "&quot;"
 var singleq = "&apos;";


 var newStr = str.replace(/&/g, ampersand).replace(/</g, left).replace(/>/g, right).replace(/"/g, doubleq).replace(/'/g, singleq);
  
return newStr;
}
```

Comment: No me queda claro por qué le asignas tantas veces de seguido a `newStr` lo que te devuelve `str.replace`. Creo que cada linea sobreescribe la anterior y la deja sin utilidad. Quizá buscabas hacerlo así: `newStr = newStr.replace(/</g, left).replace(/>/g, right).replace(/"/g, doubleq).replace(/'/g, singleq)`?

Comment: Tienes razón @GermanAlzate, lo he escrito muy rapido y me he pasado de listo XD. Gracias!